# Assertion failed: url != null is not true

Tags: api, flutter, dart

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
>   The following assertion was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#493d9):
>   Assertion failed: 
>   F:\…\painting_network_image_web.dart:23
>   url != null
>   is not true

This is the error I get when I add this codes in home.dart

```
WallpaperModel wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel();
wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel.fromMap(element);
wallpapers.add(wallpaperModel);
```

also /widget/widget.dart

```
Widget wallpapersList({List<WallpaperModel> wallpapers, context}) { return Container( padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0), child: GridView.count( shrinkWrap: true, physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 1.0, mainAxisSpacing: 5.0, crossAxisSpacing: 5.0, children: wallpapers.map((wallpaper) { return GridTile( child: Container( child: Image.network(wallpaper.src.portrait), ), ); }).toList(), ), ); }
```

[image: flutter]

this is the error I get when I execute my [code](https://github.com/mrfoxie/wallpaper) I tried to use `flutter clean` also then run `flutter run -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saw your code, please change

```
return SrcModel(
  orignal: jsonData["orignal"],
  small: jsonData["small"],
  portrait: jsonData["protrait"],
);
```

to

```
return SrcModel(
  orignal: jsonData["original"],
  small: jsonData["small"],
  portrait: jsonData["portrait"],
);
```

now I see your pics and I like your design

Comment: I can see all the elements in the terminals

Comment: can you post stacktrace ?

Comment: but I see error on url address is null. why get this error?

Comment: I can see the `building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#493d9):` message, 
Stop and  Re run your app

Comment: To print the stacktrace,  use `try{ ...  }catch(e,s){  ... print(s); }`

Comment: when I remove this three lines then it works `WallpaperModel wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel();
wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel.fromMap(element);
wallpapers.add(wallpaperModel);`

Comment: you called getTrendingWallpaper() in initState to get data from server, so before get full data , build render is completed that it cause error

Comment: @Liam who can i render it

Comment: @Liam using ` await ` would be better ?

Comment: @dev-aentgs you can not use await in initState

Comment: then what should i do if i remove await then it gives me error on     Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

Comment: @Liam I'm able to remove error it but not able to see wallpapers in it

Comment: @KenKanaki you can add  wallpaperModel to temporary list<WallpaperModel> and at the end use setState(() {   wallpapers=tempList });

Comment: 2 minutes I am debuging

Comment: @Liam any luck in debuging

Comment: @KenKanaki I changed answer. I get Result, misspelling in SrcModel I mentioned in answer

Comment: @Liam thank you for your help I really appreciate it.